# CALayer.contents drawn in UI Thread?

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer

Can you confirm that setting CALayer.contents property with CGImageRef in background thread still makes the core animation draw the contents image in main thread loop(which is UI Thread) rather than core animation thread or custom background thread which sets the contents property?

The reason I am asking this is that the core animation runs its own thread but however, it appears that when you set the CALayer.contents property the UI thread does the drawing to layer?

Answer (score 2):

My experience is that if you have a visible layer and set the contents in a background thread, it is likely that will not draw immediately.   The solution I used was to set the contents property asynchronously using a call to dispatch_async() on the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
    layer.contents = (id)myCGImage;
});
```

In particular, my example here is for working with threads using GCD, where the thread itself may long outlive the operation that you are running.   In this case, placing the assignment on the main thread, or forcing a [CATransaction flush] are two ways to indicate to the OS that you want that data to be presented to the user.

Otherwise, in the case of a GCD background thread, you are at the mercy of the thread's run loop which may not execute the [CATransaction flush] for a long time (in my experience, seconds).

Comment: That is incorrect. According to core animation and my experience, if you set the contents property of the layer from anywhere, it will draw. May be you have some other issue which is the reason its not working for you.

Comment: If you do not have something calling [CATransaction flush], it will take a long time for the data to show up if you just set the contents on the background thread.    So, as an alternative, you can call [CATransaction flush], but otherwise, your contents will be set, but undisplayed until something causes the refresh.   This can take seconds.